# Cannot change package manager to yarn

Tags: angular, angular-cli, yarnpkg, package-managers

When I try to change the package manager to yarn before creating a project, it says that I must be inside a CLI project. I'm using the following command.

```
ng config -g cli.packageManager yarn
```

Comment: are you in the directory with angular.json in it when issuing the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `yarn` properly in your project. Follow these steps:

```
ng new <project> --skip-install
cd <project>
ng config cli.packageManager yarn
yarn install
```